# Execute second batch file in cmd.exe only in case of success of first batch file execution

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I try to execute `1.bat && 2.bat` in `cmd.exe` expecting, that `2.bat` will be executed only in case of success execution `1.bat`.

1.bat

```
@echo off
echo Returning "1" from 1.bat
exit /b 1
```

2.bat

```
@echo off
echo Returning "0" from 2.bat
exit /b 0
```

Run from FAR (this result is expected):

```
>1.bat && 2.bat
Returning "1" from 1.bat
```

Run from cmd.exe (this result is not expected):

```
>1.bat && 2.bat
Returning "1" from 1.bat
Returning "0" from 2.bat
```

What should I do in order to make the combination `1.bat && 2.bat` work properly in `cmd.exe`?

Using Windows 10, version 1903.

Comment: Well, to start with open a Command Prompt window and enter `call /?`. You may also consider to verifying the error level, with `if`, _(`if /?` should show its usage information too)_.

Comment: You have to use `call 1.bat && 2.bat` as otherwise Windows command processor executes always both batch files.

Answer (score 1):

```
call 1.bat &if not errorlevel 1 call 2.bat
```

The point is that `1.bat` completed successfully, returning `errorlevel 1` hence `&&` sees a success.

Comment: The expression `call 1.bat && call 2.bat` also seems to work. But is there any way to modify `1.bat` in order to make it's error visible for ` && ` expression without `call`?

Comment: Certainly.. `one.bat&IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 two.bat`